# Visualforce table display column based on a custom field(Team__c)

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to display a column using a 'Team' field, if Team = SMB I wanted the column to display else hide it. When I use the code below the column values are rendering like I wanted but the header value is not displaying in either cases (If team = SMB or not)
So I've tried using the following code -

```
 <apex:pageblockTable value="{!shoppingCart}" var="s">    
<apex:column rendered="{!s.Opportunity.Team__c=='SMB'}">
                        <apex:facet name="header">SMB Hard Floor</apex:facet>                      
                        <apex:inputField value="{!s.SMB_Hard_Floor__c}" style="width:70px" required="false" onkeyup="refreshTotals();"/> 
                    </apex:column>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Here is an image when Team = SMB (Missing header name =SMB Hard Floor)
[image: Missing Header value but the column values are in]

When Team != SMB
[image: No Column displayed -which is what I wanted]

Comment: You should be wrapping that, you will have greater control over the objects your trying to show

Comment: I don't know exactly the logic in detail behind the component apex:pageblockTable, but the condition <apex:column rendered="{!s.Opportunity.Team__c=='SMB'}"> based on "s" that is a dynamical variable, is not the best. 

Try to have a single variable that set the visibility, it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with expression syntax in apex:column.

If you use directly false the column does not render while if the expression evaluates to the true  then the column headers still disappear